# Choose a safe separator to save a list data to db

Tags: python, string, separator

I need to convert a file list into string and save it to db.
a file list like:

```
[
  # [name, length]
  # name is in bytes
  ['111.txt', '1024'],
  ['english.txt', '2048'],
  ['some CJK words.log', '2048'],
  ....
]
```

note:

1. all file name is legal.
2. file name is not user input

now, I use:

```
if fs:
    files = []
    file_names = fs[0]
    file_lengths = fs[1]
    for i in xrange(len(file_names)):
        files.append(file_names[i] + '\#' + file_lengths[i])
    files = '\n'.join(files)

    save_to_mysql(files)
```

Because I think a file name which be present in bytes would not have `\n` and `\#`,but I am not quite sure.Is it safe to use `\#` and `\n` in my situation?

Comment: Why not use a standard file format like CSV or JSON or XML which handles these escaping issues for you?

Comment: @Jesse Rusak JSON or XML has too much redundant data.And those file formats can not be indexed by sphinx.

Comment: It appears that [XML can be indexed by Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.2.2/xmlpipe2.html)

Comment: @Jesse Rusak Right, XML can be.But it is much larger than json, that's why I can't choose it.

Comment: If this data is only going to be used in your application you might consider using Python's built-in serialization functionality. They are typically compact and you can easily share Python objects easily between other python applications. Of course there will always be the possibility that "something else just MIGHT need to use it as well, and now there is a new problem".

Comment: @MxyL pickle is like json, can not be indexed by Sphinx.Beause CJK character will be present like 'V\\u30bd\\u30fc\\u30c9\\...' ,double slash you know , can not be indexed.

Comment: I'm assuming that although your filename is not user-generated, you still have no control over what characters can be used?

Comment: Btw, your code is terrible. Use `join` instead of a concatenation and use enumerate.

Comment: @Maxime I think join must loop the string, it would be faster to use just one for loop.

Comment: @MxyL I just not sure whether a legal file name in bytes could contain `\n` and `\#`

Comment: @Mithril you are wrong. Concatenating is not a magic operation that is cheap.

Comment: @Mithril I don't know what you would consider to be legal (for example, windows explorer doesn't let me create filenames that start with a `.`), but from [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/150740/linux-windows-unix-file-names-which-characters-are-allowed-which-are-unesc) it seems like anything is fair game except a very select few, and they don't include `\n` or `\#`...

Comment: @MxyL Yeah,file in windows could not contain `\`, so I use `\n` `\#`, but I fear it would go wrong.

Comment: @Maxime You are right, I test it, join will be much faster.

Comment: How foolproof your design is really depends on how it can be used. In a controlled environment where you are certain you will only get expected input, you just need to look at what kind of input you'll get. However, just because one component is controlled, there is no guarantee that another is. For example if someone decides to write a new program that allows for new-lines and doesn't know about this issue, and now they are stuck wondering why there's a bug in their code. It is a possible scenario, but you may choose to find ways to avoid it or ignore it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution for this is to use a character that cannot appear in the texts.

But if this is not possible and it this character does appear in the text, then it have to be marked somehow, that is, *escaped*.

There are already solutions that to exactly that: you can use the C string syntax or XML or JSON or YAML...

But if you feel particular lazy, I've sometimes used the character U+0080, because it not used anywhere. But note taht if in the future you want to encode a list of strings as an element of your list... you'll have a problem! Also, you'll have to check the input strings, in case some malicious user injects this character U+0080 into your strings and start breaking things.

Comment: Thanks, I think I need two or more such character, where can I find them? Is there a list ?.And I wonder If each file name is a legal path, can I use `\n` or `\#`?

Comment: There's actually an ascii character designated as a record separator. http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/record-separator-ascii-code-30.html

Comment: @Mithril: Take a look at [the Latin1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin1) table. It is the first 256 chars of the Unicode chart. You can see that the U+008x and U+009x are unused. They are actually [_C1 control characters_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) but how cares about them.